# Why did the Witch King wait till the gate was broken before entering Minas Tirith?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, nazgul

In *The Return of the King*, the Witch King of Angmar is mounted on a flying fell beast.  When the gate of Minas Tirith is broken down, he quickly rushes in to confront Gandalf.

But he is mounted on a **flying** fell beast.  He could have entered the city whenever he wanted to by simply flying over the walls.  So why did he wait until the entrance at ground level was open?

---

*Note:  As I read this passage, I was reminded of [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cTCsRYr5KDs) YouTube video.  The Witch King is basically the dog.*

Comment: Because he's a schmuck

Comment: @Richard That needs to be an answer.

Comment: Backup.  Landing alone, he could be swarmed and overwhelmed.  Then too, we can ask whether he knows he's going to face Gandalf, or just whatever defenders happened to be on the other side of the gates.

Comment: Ever tried landing a plane downtown?

Comment: @jamesqf - His mere presence leaves men cowering in terror.  He would probably be safe from being swarmed.  When he lands on the battlefield to kill Theoden, only Eowyn has the courage to stand her ground.  Everyone else (except, eventually, Merry) runs away.

Comment: @Oldcat - planes land laterally, and try to avoid hitting people and obstacles.  Fell beasts land almost vertically, and eat people.

Comment: @jamesqf - we were both wrong.  He is on a horse at first, so he couldn't have flown over anything.  But he rides casually - "slowly", in Tolkien's words - through the battlefield, and everyone nearby, even the Orcs, stops fighting and their arms "droop" to their sides as they are overcome with fear at his passing.  He was totally unconcerned about being swarmed.

Comment: Fell Beasts don't have wings?  And want to avoid breaking them on stuff?  Do tell.

Comment: @Oldcat - birds have wings.  They land on stuff all the time.  They know how to do it without breaking anything.  They land vertically and tuck their wings back as they touch down.  That is why they can live in trees, which have more things to snag wings on than almost anything else.  I've seen Eagles being used to hunt wolves.  They don't give a f---.

Comment: If a plane is about to land in a city's downtown area, it has suffered a catastrophic failure of some kind, and will explode when it hits something.  A bird or flying fell beast would be landing there intentionally, and could do so without much risk.  Also, it wouldn't explode.

Comment: Basically, crashing planes don't get much choice regarding where they will land;  fell beasts have brains and, when making an intentional landing, can choose the safest place to land.  If anything, it makes more sense for the fell beast to fly over the wall, rather than awkwardly folding its wings, crouching down low enough to fit itself and its rider through the opening, and stuffing itself through a door intended for use by people, horses, and wagons, not giant monsters.  Imagine how screwed the fell beast would be if it got stuck halfway through the gateway.

Comment: Birds don't have 20-30 foot wingspans like fell beasts do. A fell beast folds its wings in the air it falls like a brick and dies.

Comment: @Oldcat - it obviously wouldn't fold its wings until it was safe to do so.  Birds do it all the time, and a smaller snag would cause the same degree of injury to a bird that a fell beast would suffer from a bigger snag.  Unless it is retarded, it knows what it can and cannot do.  It would still be better off flying over than walking through a tiny gate and having to squeeze itself and its rider through.  FFS, in the movie a fell beast DOES land in the city.  Others fly close enough to grab catapults, and swoop through Osgiliath, and fly all up in an erupting volcano's business.

Comment: @Oldcat And fell beasts don't live in trees as birds do. So whats the problem?

Comment: Can I just say, this "debate" should be sent for inclusion in a Big Bang script :)

Comment: If it were a Michael Bay movie, the fell beast would explode. And then the Witch King would come walking out of the flames... casually pursuing an injured Sarah Conn- er, Eowyn-er, never mind.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the book, it's because he'd only just arrived, **on horseback**, evidently having accompanied Grond (and some additional troops) to the battlefield.

> **Over the hills of slain a hideous shape appeared: a horseman, tall,
>   hooded, cloaked in black. Slowly, trampling the fallen, he rode forth,
>   heeding no longer any dart.** He halted and held up a long pale sword.
>   And as he did so a great fear fell on all, defender and foe alike; and
>   the hands of men drooped to their sides, and no bow sang. For a moment
>   all was still. The drums rolled and rattled. With a vast rush Grond
>   was hurled forward by huge hands. It reached the Gate. It swung. A
>   deep boom rumbled through the City like thunder running in the clouds.
>   ... And suddenly upon the last stroke the Gate of Gondor broke. As if
>   stricken by some blasting spell it burst asunder: there was a flash of
>   searing lightning, and the doors tumbled in riven fragments to the
>   ground. In rode the Lord of the Nazgûl. A great black shape against
>   the fires beyond he loomed up, grown to a vast menace of despair. **In
>   rode the Lord of the Nazgûl, under the archway that no enemy ever yet
>   had passed, and all fled before his face.**

Comment: There's also the symbolic effect: flying over the walls is no big deal.  Passing through the gate that no enemy has ever passed, that's a different matter.

Comment: This answer is somewhat more nuanced than your comment to the question. \*nodnod\*